# Unable to web deploy to Linux App Service from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-appservice

For about 2 weeks now I am unable to web deploy from Visual Studio 2019 16.9.6. I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application that I am trying to web deploy to a Linux App Service on Azure. When I try to publish I get the following errors:

```
Publish has encountered an error.
Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\ken\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF3BF.tmp"

An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
```

Prior to two weeks ago I had no issues. The following is a list of items I have tried:

- Stopped and started the app service
- Stopped the app service and tried deploying while it was stopped
- Reset the publish profile and re-imported it into Visual Studio

If I edit the publish profile and click "Validate Connection" it fails and gives the same error message as above:

```
An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
```

I am able to publish locally and use an FTPS client to connect to the app service and manually deploy the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the current publish profile and instead of downloading it from the Azure portal I used the new publish profile wizard built into Visual to create the publish profile. Once I did that everything started to deploy with no issues. I looked at what the difference is and it seems the publish profile I downloaded from Azure was missing an XML element called "IsLinux".

Comment: thanks, this fixed the error that i was getting.